# Re-dropping Multiple Google Maps Markers Without Repaint On Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I've got a largish (~1,300) set of markers that I'm placing on a map over a timeline.  Basically it's like playing a video where over the time sequence, markers are placed using `google.maps.Animation.DROP` on a map.  We have standard video/audio player-type controls that allow you to navigate the timeline: play/pause, skip to start, skip to end, and a scrubber bar to move arbitrarily within the timeline.

If I start with the map empty and the timeline paused at the beginning and then jump to the end there's a brief delay as all of those marker objects are created and then they all drop onto the map together.  This is fine.

Once a marker's been placed and the user moves backward in the timeline (to a point where a particular marker should no longer be visible) I do a `marker.setMap(null)` and the marker is hidden.  From what I've [read](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) this is the correct way to remove a marker and it works.

The big problem manifests if you create/drop all (or a large number) of the markers, then navigate back in the timeline (such that the large number of markers is removed), and then jump forward again.  This creates a nasty flash of pins on the map that then disappear and suddenly drop from the top of the map.

As mentioned, the correct effect (pins drop in without appearing on the map beforehand) happens the **first** time the pins drop, but subsequent drops cause this odd behavior.  For small numbers of pins it's largely imperceptible, but with a lot of pins it's much more distracting.

It seems like there must be something in the internal state of the marker that `marker.setMap(null)` is not truly resetting, but I'm not at all sure what that might be.

I originally created new markers as needed and then destroyed them when they disappeared, but this overhead made things sluggish.  In theory I feel like my approach should work throughout, but I basically get one good shot with the right effect and repeats behave badly.

Does anyone see something I'm doing wrong or have suggestions on how to make this behave?

The logic that adds pins, shows, and hides is roughly as follows:

```
Realtime.prototype.placePin = function(ent) {
    var ctxt = this;

    ent.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(ent.lat, ent.lng);

    ent.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ent.latLng,
        map: null,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        optimized: false
    });
};

Realtime.prototype.tick = function(force_tick) {
    var ctxt = this;

    if ((!ctxt.playing || ctxt.dragging) && !force_tick) {
        return;
    } else {
        ctxt.time += ctxt.per_tick;
    }
    ctxt.nowDate = new Date(ctxt.time * 1000);

    ctxt.pins_to_drop = [];     
    for (var i = 0, l = ctxt.entries.length; i < l; i++) {
        var ent = ctxt.entries[i];
        var ent_date = new Date(ent.created + ' UTC');
        if (ent_date < ctxt.nowDate) {
            if (!ent.marker || ent.marker.map == null) {
                if (!ent.marker) {
                    ctxt.placePin(ent);
                }
                ctxt.pins_to_drop.push(ent);
            }
        } else {
            if (ent.marker && ent.marker.map != null) {
                ent.marker.setMap(null);
            }
        }
    }

    ctxt.updateUI();

};

Realtime.prototype.updateUI = function() {
    var ctxt = this;

    for (var i = 0, l = ctxt.pins_to_drop.length; i < l; i++) {
        var ent = ctxt.pins_to_drop[i];
        ent.marker.setMap(null);
        ent.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        ent.marker.setMap(ctxt.map);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Try this: wait for load, drop pins, wait for drop, hide pins, wait for hide, re-drop pins -- http://jsfiddle.net/theraccoonbear/50437ptm/6/

Comment: That example they always all drop at the same time.

Comment: Correct; they're supposed to.  The problem is that when you drop, hide, re-drop--the pins on the re-drop are drawn on the map, disappear, and then drop in.  Are you not seeing that behavior?

Comment: I can see the behavior you're describing. This does look like a bug in Maps where setting the map shows the pin before the animation call. The obvious work-around would be to regenerate the markers each time, though it's an unpleasant solution.

Comment: A suggestion (which does not use Google.Maps.Marker): create a _Google Maps overlay_ and use d3.js to fill it with markers and create transitions. It is very fast with large amount of pins.

Answer (score -1):

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theraccoonbear/50437ptm/6/)
and I am not sure if it solves your problem but another way to *hide/unhide* a marker is by calling `setVisible()` of marker as `marker.setVisible(boolean)`.
The drop animation in this case will work only for first time as `setVisible()` does not associate the marker with the map again since its already associated.

Comment: If it doesn't address the second and subsequent pin drops--and that approach does not--it does not fix the issue.